# How to handle CommandError exceptions in Django tests

Tags: django, django-testing, django-manage.py, django-tests

I'm creating a `Management Command` in which I raise a `CommandError` exception when something goes wrong.

One of my test cases executes the command in a way that it will raise the exception so the result of the test is Error.

How can I make it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected behaviour is exception, you can use the assertRaises, look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises